# Extra energy in dual mass-spring systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator, spring

Below is a Dual mass spring system placed on a smooth surface(no friction), let us assume the spring constant as $k$ in this case.

[image: Dual mass spring system]

Now if we create a small extension in the spring of value $x_o$, the two masses will perform simple harmonic motion(SHM) individually with amplitudes $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively such that $A_1$ + $A_2$ = $x_o$. Now the total energy of said system is given by $\frac{1}{2}kx_o^2$ and the energies of their individual oscillations would be $\frac{1}{2}kA_1^2$ and $\frac{1}{2}kA_2^2$. But $\frac{1}{2}kA_1^2$ + $\frac{1}{2}kA_2^2$ $\neq$ $\frac{1}{2}kx_o^2$. So what is this extra energy being used for? Clearly it isn't being used for SHM as it doesn't come under the energy of the the masses' individual oscillations. So I am unable to tell what it is being used for!

I have another question as well. Their individual maximum kinetic energies are related as follows: $\frac{1}{2}mv_1^2$ + $\frac{1}{2}Mv_2^2$ $=$ $\frac{1}{2}kx_o^2$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the individual masses' maximum velocities. But maximum kinetic energy of a body performing SHM should be equal to its maximum potential energy! So $\frac{1}{2}kA_1^2$ should be equal to $\frac{1}{2}mv_1^2$ and similarly $\frac{1}{2}kA_2^2$ should be equal to $\frac{1}{2}Mv_2^2$. But this would go against our equation that $\frac{1}{2}kA_1^2$ + $\frac{1}{2}kA_2^2$ $\neq$ $\frac{1}{2}kx_o^2$! So I am quite confused about what is happening here!

So can anybody explain these to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to analyse both masses together as a single SHM system - you cannot split then into two independent SHM components.

Suppose we start with the spring at its natural length and move mass $m$ to the left by a distance $x_1$ and mass $M$ to the right by a distance $x_2$. The force that the spring exerts on both masses is now $k(x_1+x_2)$. So if we move mass $m$ from $x_1=0$ to $x_1=A_1$ and we move mass $M$ from $x_2=0$ to $x_2=A_2$ then the total energy stored in the spring is

$\int_0^{A_1+A_2} ky \space dy$

where $y=x_1+x_2$, and

$ \int_0^{A_1+A_2} ky \space dy = \frac 1 2 k (A_1+A_2)^2 = \frac 1 2 k x_0^2$

so there is no "extra energy".

When we release the masses the equation of motion of mass $m$ is

$m \frac {d^2x_1}{dt^2} = -k(x_1+x_2)$

and for mass $M$ it is

$M \frac {d^2x_2}{dt^2} = -k(x_1+x_2)$

Adding these together we get

$\frac {d^2y}{dt^2} = -k'y$

where $k' = k(\frac 1 m + \frac 1 M)$, and $y(0) = x_0$, $\frac{dy}{dt}(0) = 0$. So

$y = x_0 \cos (\sqrt{k'}t) \\ \Rightarrow \frac {d^2x_1}{dt^2} = -\frac k m y = -\frac {kx_0}{m} \cos (\sqrt{k'}t) \\ \Rightarrow  v_1 = \frac  {dx_1}{dt} =  -\frac {kx_0}{m\sqrt{k'}} \sin (\sqrt{k'}t)$

Similarly

$v_2 = \frac {dx_2}{dt} =  -\frac {kx_0}{M\sqrt{k'}} \sin (\sqrt{k'}t)$

When the spring returns to its natural length, $y=0$ and $\cos \sqrt{k'}t = 0$ so $\sin \sqrt{k'}t = 1$. So the kinetic energy of the system is

$\frac 1 2 m v_1^2 + \frac 1 2 M v_2^2 = \frac {k^2 x_0^2}{2k'} \left( \frac 1 m + \frac 1 M \right) = \frac {kk'x_0^2}{2k'} = \frac 1 2 k x_0^2$

In other words, all of the potential energy stored in the spring has been converted into kinetic energy, as expected.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! I understand now!

Comment: so, $y$ is a function of $x_1$ and $x_2$, now why how did you figure out that $-ky dy $is the correct differential to integrate for total energY?

Comment: @DDD4C4U You can imagine holding one mass stationary and moving the other from $y=0$ to $y=x_0$. For each increment $\delta y$ you are storing $ky \delta y$ energy in the spring.

Comment: Yes that applies in that case, but what about the general case for which you did it in the post? I wish for an intuition on that

Comment: @DDD4C4U The configuration of the system after stretching the spring is the same in either case, and the energy stored in the spring depends only on the configuration of the system, not on the route taken to get there.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the magnitude of the maximum displacement from its equilibrium position of mass $m$ and $X$ be the magnitude of the maximum displacement from its equilibrium position of mass $M$.

Conservation of momentum for the system requires $m\dot x = M\dot X \Rightarrow mx=MX$.

For this system the natural frequency of oscillation is given by $\omega^2 = \dfrac{k(m+M)}{mM}$.

The maximum kinetic energy of the system is $\dfrac 12 m \omega^2 x^2 +\dfrac 12 m \omega^2 X^2$.

Putting in the value of $\omega^2$ and multiplying out gives the kinetic energy as

$\dfrac 12 kx^2+\dfrac 12 k \left(\dfrac mM \right)x\, x +\dfrac 12 k \left(\dfrac Mm \right)X\, X+\dfrac 12 kX^2 = \dfrac 12 kx^2+\dfrac 12 k\, X\, x +\dfrac 12 k\, x\, X+\dfrac 12 kX^2=\dfrac 12 k(x+X)^2 = \text{elastic potential energy at the start}$.

It is possible to do a more general analysis to show that the total energy of the system is constant.

Comment: I see, very insightful, thanks so much!

Comment: Why were you able to do $m\dot{x}  = M \dot{X}$? I mean when you give small perturbation to the system initially aren't you introducing some energy into it and hence a non zero net momentum?

While I accept your results, I don't think I understand the intuition behind it

Comment: @DDD4C4U Think about the idea that the centre of mass does not move and the conservation of linear momentum.  Linear momentum is conserved if no *external* forces act the the system of two masses and the spring.  I have assumed that after stretching the spring the two masses start from rest.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thank you ^^